# How to access a Subfolder in a Shared folder using smbclient

Tags: permissions, samba

I have created a share on a Redhat distribution to a specific directory by editing the smb.conf file:

```
[MyShare]
path = /path/to/MyShare
guest ok = yes
read only = no
browseable = yes
public = yes
writable = yes
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
```

and then I've restarted the samba service.

This folder has sub folders.

I can connect to the shared folder with an `smbclient` and a `GUEST` user directly by using the following command: `smbclient //10.0.0.1/MyShare/ -U GUEST`

But when I try to connect to the subfolder like so: `smbclient //10.0.0.1/MyShare/MySubFolder/ -U GUEST`, I receive an error: `tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME`

The question is: how can I access the subfolder directly from an smbclient without creating a specific share for it?

Comment: I don't think you can do what you want without sharing every folder. When you are connected you can cd to the desired subfolder.

Comment: @nobody This is bad news for me. Is it written anywhere?

Comment: The manpage ( https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smbclient.1.html ) outlines the structure of a servicename which contains the name of the share, but not folders inside of it. Depending on what you attempt to do, it shouldn't be impossible to issue a cd command first (and put or get afterwards).